# Installation Object in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have multiple queries as follows:
1. Where is the parse Installation object located? is it in cloud or locally in the app?
2. Can I access the Installation object in the cloud?
3. Is the installation id different every time installation is done on same device (for android and iOS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse installation object is, at least on iOS devices, cached locally and stored in Parse (you can access it in the data browser).  The installation id is different each time the app is installed, based on my experience.

Comment: When do you need to create an Installation object? Isn't it used only for when a user registers for Push Notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for iOS, but I imagine behavior is similar for Android:

1. The PFInstallation object is cached locally. You can retrieve it with `PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];`
   You can save it to the cloud with `[currentInstallation saveInBackground]` or any of the other save methods.
2. Until you save the PFInstallation (as above) you will not have access to it in the cloud or data browser.
3. The objectId of the PFInstallation object is different every time the app is newly installed on the same device -- this is because a new PFInstallation object is created for the new install. If you have saved a previous PFInstallation object to the cloud, that record remains there, but there's no longer any way to tie it to the device. `[PFInstallation currentInstallation]` will now retrieve the new installation record. Note that this is true only for fresh installs, i.e., if you delete the app from the device and the install it again. If you simply install a new version of the app over a previously installed version, no new PFInstallation object is created (though the updatedAt value of the old PFInstallation record is updated if you then retrieve and save the object).